Solving a stochastic equation by characteristic functions
Based on the work of Nicolas Curien and Takis Konstantopoulos titled Iterating Brownian motions, ad libitum I would like to prove the following (based on the last paragraph of the proof of Proposition 3):
Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables. $Y$ is a standard normal distribution, whereas X is an exponential distribution with parameter $2$ (it has a density $f_X (x) = \mathbf{1} _{x>0} \cdot 2 \cdot \exp (-2x)$). Therefore $f_{\sqrt{X}} (x) = \mathbf{1}_{x>0}\cdot 4x \cdot \exp (-2x^2)$ and $f_{|Y|} = \mathbf{1}_{x\geq 0} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \cdot \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$.
The claim I would like to prove is the following:
$X \overset{(d)}{=} \sqrt{X} \cdot |Y|$
So far I tried, according to the Wikipedia-article about the distribution of a product of two random variables, the following:

Show, that $X$ and $\sqrt{X}\cdot |Y|$ have the same density. Ends in having analytically-non-solvable integrals
Show, that the characteristic function in terms of probability of $X$ and $\sqrt{X}\cdot |Y|$ is the same, and a similar problem
Trying to use the power-series representation to simplify as much as possible any function did not yield any result either.

Iterating Brownian motions, ad libitum claims "Guided by the result of [Tur04],
an easy computation shows that the exponential variable of density $f_X$ also satisfies
$X \overset{(d)}{=} \sqrt{X} \cdot |Y|$ thus completing the proof of the proposition."
Can someone give me a hint?
The random variable $X$ originates from $\mathcal{X} := \lim _{n \to \infty} \prod _{i=0} ^{n-1} |\mathcal{N}|^{2^{-i}}$ with iid standard normal distributions $(\mathcal{N}_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. The reason, why $\mathcal{X} \overset{(d)}{=} \sqrt{\mathcal{X}} \cdot |Y|$, is clear (I have calculated it).
The overall goal is to show, that $X \overset{(d)}{=} \mathcal{X}$
I hope, You could help me a bit.
Best regards

I got it.
We have to use the Mellin-transform mentioned in the Wikipedia article about the distribution of the product of two random variables.
The Wikipedia-article quotes the property, that for independent random variables $\sqrt{X}, |Y|$ we have $\mathcal{M} _{\sqrt{X}|Y|} (s) =\mathcal{M} _{\sqrt{X}} (s) \mathcal{M} _{|Y|} (s)$.
Using Wolfram Alpha (type: "Mellon transform " and calculate) we obtain, that $(\mathcal{M} _{\sqrt{X}} (s))\cdot (\mathcal{M} _{|Y|} (s)) = (2^{\frac{1-s}{2}}\Gamma (\frac{s+1}{2}))\cdot (\frac{2^{\frac{s-1}{2}}\Gamma (\frac{s}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}})=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})\Gamma (\frac{s+1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}} = (*)$
By using Legendre's duplication Formula we obtain
$(*)= 2^{1-s} \Gamma (s)$
By Mellin-transforming X we obtain $\mathcal{M} _{X} (s) = 2^{1-s} \Gamma (s)$
Knowing, that the Mellin-transform uniquely characterises a distribution, we have shown, that $X \overset{(d)}{=} \sqrt{X}|Y|$
